# Python Data Frame - nested comma in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

The data file is like given below. How shall I read through data frame?

```
'''
 [[2020,1,22],0,0,0], 
 [[2020,1,23],0,0,0], 
 [[2020,1,24],0,0,0], 
 [[2020,1,25],0,0,0], 
 [[2020,1,26],0,0,0], 
 [[2020,1,27],0,0,0], 

'''
```

Comment: You could prepare and modify the input with a script to better suit the CSV format: separate the year, month and day into individual columns, remove all square brackets, and remote the trailing comma. Then read it as a standard CSV file.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I modified like this and then using quotechar ='~'
~2020,1,22~,0,0,0,
~2020,1,23~,0,0,0,
~2020,1,24~,0,0,0,
~2020,1,25~,0,0,0,
~2020,1,26~,0,0,0,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data as a single column of strings:

```py
df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', header=None)

# or read as csv with sep='\n'
# df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\n', header=None)
```

Parse the list-looking strings into actual lists with `ast.literal_eval` and expand them into columns with `apply(pd.Series)`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
df = df[0].str.strip(', ').apply(literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)
```

Convert the date lists to real `datetime`s:

```py
df[0] = df[0].agg(lambda x: pd.to_datetime('-'.join(map(str, x))))
```

Output:

```
           0  1  2  3
0 2020-01-22  0  0  0
1 2020-01-23  0  0  0
2 2020-01-24  0  0  0
3 2020-01-25  0  0  0
4 2020-01-26  0  0  0
5 2020-01-27  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this forum. Need 15 reputations it seems. Accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: One catch with `read_fwf` is that it's for fixed-width formats, but there's no guarantee that the lines will all be the same width. For example, the month that is `1` on one line could be `11` on another, or the zeros in the 2nd through 4th columns could be replaced with any other numbers.

Comment: @jjramsey it's flexible enough to handle that unless you explicitly specify `colspecs` or `widths`. the main caveat here is if there are spaces in the original data, in which case `read_fwf` will infer more columns

Comment: `read_csv` with `sep='\n'` also works if `read_fwf` gives you trouble

Comment: tdy and jjramsey ,  you guys are right. fwf gave problem at the third line mentioned below. 
[[2020,5,8],3344,1111,96],
[[2020,5,9],3113,1414,116],
[[2020,5,10],4353,1668,111],
used csv instead.  But didn't give problem here 
[[2020,2,9],0,0,0],
[[2020,2,10],0,0,0], It worked. Thanks.